# Port Already in Use / Start of Tomcat failed

Tags: tomcat, netbeans, deployment, port

**Netbeans : Port Already in Use / Start of Tomcat failed**

I am facing recurring issue with Netbeans when Apache Tomcat is chosen as server instead of bloat glassFish server.

***Issue 1 :*** Port NNNN is already in use for GlassFish : After so much research I could find that I had Oracle DB server installed long back which was using same port. Changed it (One can try stopping the server temporarily too) . Projects on run glassfish run fine.

***Issue 2 :*** Port NNNN is already in use for Apache Tomcat : With the help of some blogs I learned that some application would be occupied with same port. Identify the PID . Kill the process from Task Manager. Restart Tomcat by Netbeans either by running web project or Right click on Tomcat and run it on Servers window. Server starts with Catalina scripts. Displays message "Starting Tomcat, Waiting for Tomcat. " After time out of 3 mins it says starting of

Tomcat failed and directs at nbproject build xml page 1070 line .

*Starting Tomcat process...
Waiting for Tomcat...
Starting of Tomcat failed.
C:...............................\testApp\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1070: Deployment error: Starting of Tomcat failed.
See the server log for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 3 minutes 3 seconds)*

I dont know what is wrong. May be Netbeans trying is waiting for tomcat to respond internally or it fails at deploying WAR file from within.

I checked credentials it uses to login Tomcat .It is fine. manager-script role also defined in tomcat-users.xml properly. Server log is empty at Netbeans . However if I check in logs folder , it gives less info to debug.

***Issue 3 :*** Rerun project on Netbeans with Tomcat . It says port already occupied.
Starting of Tomcat failed, the server port 9090 is already in use.

This port is set for Tomcat only. So its not conflicting with any other server/service.

Could it be IDE issue. Why should it start the server which is already on in the first place. It should run shutdown.bat internally and then run startup.bat if thats what it is looking for

**Alternate :** Deploying .WAR file from Tomcat homepage manually does work.

If someone is facing same issue with Netbeans-Tomcat or have solution please share.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This was the issue with the version of tomcat. I used previous version and the error went